# Second derivative bounded above

Tags: calculus

Can somebody suggest a function that is (i) NOT bounded below, (ii) the second derivative is bounded above?

$f(x)=x^2$ is not a good example since $f(x) \geq 0$ (bounded below) and $f''(x)=2$ is bounded above.

Comment: How about $f(x)=-x$ ?

Comment: @JohnSmith Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It the bound on the second derivative is tight, we have

$$f''(x)=f''_{max}$$

and

$$f(x)=f''_{max}\frac{x^2}2+cx+c'$$

which is unbounded below for any $f''_{max}<0$ (or $f''_{max}=0$ and $c<0$).

---

Interestingly,

$$f(x)=-e^x=f''(x)$$ is unbounded below and bounded above.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from your idea let consider $f(x)=-x^2\le 0\implies f''(x)=-2.$

Answer (score 1):

For $n\in\mathbb N$, consider $f_n(x)=-x^{2n}$ has second derivative $f_n''(x)=-2n(2n-1)x^{2n-2}$.

$f_n$ is not bounded below, and $f_n''$ is bounded above.